# How to include a cell value in a FILTER formula

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-filter

I want to import data from the main datasheet (Sheet 1) into a person specific sheet based on if their name is in column E or F in sheet 1. Currently using the following formula =FILTER('Sheet1'!B8:D, ('Sheet1'!E8:E="John")+('Sheet1'!F8:F="John"))
This works perfectly but since I have used this formula on three different spots on the employee specific sheet I prefer link to a cell with the name of the employee instead of typing in the name of employee in all those formula's.

Say the name of the employee (John) is at the top of that person specific sheet (in cell A1), how do I link to that in the FILTER formula? Because  =FILTER('Sheet1'!B8:D, ('Sheet1'!E8:E="A1")+('Sheet1'!F8:F="A1")) does not work.

Hope anyone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cell references don't take quotation marks `""` only text strings do.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B8:D, 
   (Sheet1!E8:E=A1)+ 
   (Sheet1!F8:F=A1))
```